# How can we make two inputs appear on the same line?

Tags: visual-c++

In c++, if we make program to take input from user, it is either some integer or character.

After that input, the next output or next input is written on the next line automatically.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    std::cout<<"Enter two numbers to add\n";
    std::cin>>a;
    std::cin>>b;
    std::cout<< a+b;
}
```

the output is like this

```
Enter two numbers to add
3
5
8
```

I want 3 and 5 written in same line..

Comment: SuperUser is not about programming, this rather belongs to StackExchange. Flagged for moving.

Comment: @slchk "Stack Exchange" is a quite generic destination ;) I suggest StackOverflow instead.

Comment: @Daniel Whoops, I spent waaay too many hours in front of the screen today.

Comment: While this does belong on Stack Overflow, and probably will be moved there shortly, you will probably want to provide a coded example of what you are trying to do and/or what you have already. When asking for coding help, you will get the best response if you provide at least some code.

Comment: Please post a small but complete program that demonstrates what you're talking about, or at least *some* code. Your question is probably answerable, but only if we can see the exact code that's causing you problems.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is called "parsing".  You take the entire input in as 1 variable, and split it up using whatever method is appropriate for you.  Some programming languages have some built-in methods for breaking up a string input into an array based on a value you supply.  You might want to take a look at: [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/c-how-to-split-a-string)

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP's problem is. He speaks of writing output across multiple lines rather than on one line - what has that to do with parsing?

Comment: @razlebe: Quite a lot. The root cause of the OP's problem is that, when taking an input per line, most terminals will render the newline so that _any_ further activity will render on the next line. Parsing two inputs from one single line of input will, clearly, prevent the second input from appearing on a second line in the terminal.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - Fair point. :) I guess the water was muddied for me by that first sentence in the answer. Parsing is a related problem he'll have to solve once he understands the root cause of his current problem, rather than the root cause of the problem in of itself.

Comment: @Numair Siddique This answer and the comments here should have helped you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

That the input is appearing on two seperate lines has nothing to do with your program; this is because, while typing the input, you pressed `<Enter>` after `3`. The resulting newline was rendered by your terminal / console, not your program.

Using `istream::operator>>( int )` will automatically skip leading whitespace. So your user could also *write* `3 5` on one line. `std::cin>>a;` would consume the `3`, and `std::cin>>b;` would skip the space and consume the `5`. Your terminal / console would look like this:

```
Enter two numbers to add
3 5
8
```

Note that this is completely unrelated to your program code, though. If the user presses `<Enter>` between numbers, there is nothing you can do about it, short of taking over complete control of the terminal / console.

This **can** be done, using [`_getch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) on Windows, [`ncurses`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) on many other systems, or whatever the OS in question provides. You would be reading keypresses directly, without the terminal / console echoing what is entered. You would then be responsible for the echo, line editing etc.

That is a completely different question, though.